# чем лучше слать уведомления на телефон как pushbullet?

Tags: android, push-уведомления

поюзал пушбуллет, оказалось эти гады бесплатно предоставляют только  500 пушев на месяц, маловато.

Вот ищу чем бы его заменить, гугл выдал целую кучу вариантов, но перебирать их 
все как то нет времени.

Чем можно заменить пушбуллет? критерии выбора простые:

```
1. можно слать уведомление с ссылкой
2. не тупящая программа на android (пушбулет вобще забывал уведомление играть, как за такое можно платить?)
3. отсутствие лимита сообщений или лимит в несколько тысяч
4. возможность бесплатного использования
```

Comment: Не знаю что за пушбуллет, но, возможно, вам FireBase от гугла подойдёт?

Comment: Это что еще программу писать? а как мне потом это связать с скриптом на Python апи я там не нашел

Comment: Ну, в теории вы просто делаете скриптом запрос к FireBase, передавая ID девайса, а дальше FireBase делает пуш

Comment: на телефон что-то ставить надо?

Comment: Ну... На телефоне должно быть приложение, завязанное на FireBase которое, собственно и будет принимать сообщения

Comment: поковырялся пару часов, создал прогу. теперь у меня собственный бесплатный пушбулет хахаха. спасибо за наводку!!!

Comment: осталось только понять как отрывать ссылку в браузере